Arduino circuit design help
Below is my current design for an Arduino project that contains a proximity limit switch and a relay to toggle on/off a small 12volt heater. All other components are very straightforward and are excluded for simplicity.
Everything seems to be working well and reacting as expected. My question is if anyone sees any issues or would recommend any changes with this schematic before I design out a custom PCB?

Thanks.

You do realize that the optocouplers aren't actually doing anything for you, right?  Optocouplers are to allow isolated communcation between circuits with separate power supplies.  Your circuit has all the components sharing a common power supply, so there's no isolation at all.

Make sure you use proper creepage and clearance on the AC input

With all other components eliminated, it's hard to say for sure.  But make sure that AC-DC converter has plenty of decoupling caps on the output.  My experience is that they tend to have a decent amount high frequency noise on them.

@JRE We don't have a part number for the Proximity switch, but it could be outputing 12V, which is too high for the uC.  But a voltage divider would be easier/cheaper, unless he needs open collector for some reason.

U3 is doing nothing.  It's shorted out.

@VoltageSpike Good point, but the PSU is separate from the PCB, and only the 12-volt is connected to the board. I should have explained this better.

@JRE Yes, I needed the optos for use with the 12-volt proximity switch. However, I am thinking of getting rid of these since the switches are NPN and are just sinking the controller signal (Pull-Ups). Your comment made me rethink this.

@Aaron I do not have any decoupling caps planned out, I don't have experience with these. I am reading up on them now. Any advice you can give would be helpful too. As for U3, this was just a simple oversight in my schematic design.

@ElectroRag This is really confusing because you have the optos and the arudino on the same schematic page, usually this translates directly to the PCB.
